# REQUIRED: get_bloginfo('template_url') was found in the file search.php. Use get_template_directory_uri() instead

Tags: php, functions, codex

Theme Check error →

```
REQUIRED: get_bloginfo('template_url') was found in the file search.php. Use get_template_directory_uri() instead.
Line 21: <img src='<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/no_results_found.png'/>
```

I acted and made the changes, but the image is now not coming in live webpage →

```
<img src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/img/no_results_found.png'/>
```

Is there any mistake in the above?

Comment: What gets shown in as the Image src? How does it differ before and after?

Comment: Image doesn't appear when it needed to be.

Comment: I understood that from the question, but that's not enough information to answer the question, what kind of URL does it show? How is it different before and after you change the code? Also what errors are in your browsers console/dev tools?

Comment: `<img src="">` → src empty in browser.

Comment: I'm still wondering how is that possible. You have a harcoded `/img/no_results_found.png` in your `src`, which I'm not sure how it disappeared.

Comment: @Jack Johanson → based on the answers answer I removed single quote and used a double quote and it worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the image in a child theme? If so, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead as it will grab the child theme URL. `get_template_directory_uri()` grabs the parent theme.

Depending on your PHP version adding a semicolon also might make a difference, and typically image src uses double quotes rather than single.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/no_results_found.png" />
```